# Limit $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac {(\ln(x))^k}x$

Tags: limits

The limit is $$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac {(\ln(x))^k}x$$ $\forall k \in N, k \ge 1$

For $k = 1$ or $2$, the limit is fairly easy to solve using the Stolz–Cesàro theorem. Intuitively, because $ln(x)$ grows so much slower than $x$, the answer should be $0$. But how can we mathematically solve the limit for any positive integer k?

Comment: Is that meant to be $(\ln x)^k$ or $\ln (x^k)$ ?

Comment: $(lnx)^k$ I will fix this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\ln^kx}{x}= \left(\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{k\ln x^{\frac1{k}}}{x^{\frac1{k}}} \right)^k = k^k \left( \lim_{y\to\infty} \frac{\ln y}{y} \right)^k= 0
$$

Comment: @egreg thanks for that correction! i will make the required edit

Comment: We could note that the statement is valid also for non integer $k>0$. It's even valid for $k\le 0$ (this case is obvious).

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you meant $(\log x)^k$ just set $x = e^t$ and $\log x = t$. You can show the limit in many ways now, e.g. by applying L'Hospital's rule.

Answer (score 3):

If $\log x = u$, $x=e^u$, your limit becomes
$$
\lim_{u \to +\infty} \frac{u^k}{e^u}.
$$
This limit is zero, and you can convince yourself about this by differentiating $k$ times.

Answer (score 3):

Use L'Hospital's rule and induction:
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\ln^kx}{x}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{k\ln^{k-1}x}x=0 $$
by induction hypothesis.